# Need help determining maximum and minimum of user inputs

Tags: java, max, min

I am trying to determine if each input a user provides is the `max` or `min` out of all of their inputs, and then assign that input to a variable `high` or `low`

```
int inputnum = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double lastinput = 0;
    double high;
    double low;
    double average;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    high = 0;
    low = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number. Type 0 to quit.");
    lastinput = input.nextDouble(); //reads input
    sum += lastinput; //add to sum
    if (lastinput != 0) {
        inputnum += 1; //counts number of inputs (except 0)
    }
    if (lastinput > high && lastinput != 0) {
        high = lastinput;
    }
    if (lastinput < low && lastinput != 0) {
        low = lastinput;
    }

    average = (sum / inputnum);

} while (lastinput !=0); //repeat unless user inputs 0
```

The problem is that I cannot declare the variable without assigning it a value (for example 0). If a user inputs `3`, `5`, and `7` for example, the `low` value is still defined as `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your following condition:

```
if (lastinput < low && lastinput != 0) {
    low = lastinput;
}
```

Notice that the variable `low` is 0 initially. So if your actual minimum is higher than 0, then it will not affect the value of `low` because it is 0. There can be several logical solutions to this:

1. **Use a sentinel value** : Initialise low with the highest possible value of double so that the user input is always lower, therefore affects the value of `low`

   ```
   double low = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   ```
2. **Change the if condition** : You could change the `if` condition to account for the fact that the initial value is 0.

   ```
   if (low==0 || (lastinput < low && lastinput != 0)) {
       low = lastinput;
   }
   ```

Comment: Second solution will also get rid of the weird behavior of the first solution if no inputs are given (in such case, first solution will have `low > `high`). +1

Comment: Yes @JiriTousek . But this is just a corner case and can be taken care of any way the programmer wants too. It depends from a coder to coder.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you intialize `low` to zero, and all the values you enter are bigger, so it will never be updated. You have to assign it to the highest possible value - `low = Double.MAX_VALUE;` so all the other values will be lower than it.

Similarly, you should initialize high as

```
high = Double.MIN_VALUE;
```

Comment: `double` it is :)

Comment: Very strange, I get 0. Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a maximum value for `low` by default or else the condition `lastinput < low` for non-negative inputs would always be `false` and 0 remains as your output.

```
double low = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `low` and `high` can be initialed by your first input before your loop.